# What's the best way to train a custom corpora for speech to text?

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am very new to speech to text modeling and could use a little bit of a tutorial in how to best train a speech to text corpus. The problem I'm trying to solve is one where there are unrecognized parts of speech like "nah man". Should I put the entire sentence that contains the unrecognized words into a corpus file or just the unrecognized words, like "nah man"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I reread the documentation and you answered it quite clearly. `The accuracy of transcription can depend largely on how words are defined in a model and how speakers say them. To improve the service's accuracy, provide as many examples as possible of how custom words are used in the domain. The more sentences you add that represent the context in which speakers use words from the domain, the better the service's recognition accuracy. The service does not apply a simple word-matching algorithm; its transcription depends on the context in which words are used.`